# Get object type from empty Swift Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, generics

Is there a way to get instance of Array element from the empty array? (I need `dynamic` properties because I use some KVC methods on `NSObject`)

```
import Foundation

class BaseClass: NSObject {
    func myFunction() {
        doWork()
    }
}

class Car: BaseClass {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
}

class Bus: BaseClass {
    dynamic var seats: Int = 0
}

var cars = Array<Car>()
```

What I need is a vay to get instance of empty Car object from this empty array, for example like this:

```
var carFromArray = cars.instanceObject() // will return empty Car object
```

I know that I can use:

```
var object = Array<Car>.Element()
```

but this doesn't work for me since I get array from function parameter and I don't know it's element class.

I have tried to write my own type that will do this, and it works, but then I cannot mark it as `dynamic` since it cannot be represented in Objective C. I tried to write extension of Array

```
extension Array {
    func instanceObject<T: BaseClass>() -> T? {
        return T()
    }
}
```

but when I use it, it sometimes throws error `fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type`

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Obviously if the array contains any elements you can pass the array or an element and we can learn its dynamic type. But if you pass the empty array to a function, that function cannot learn what type of thing array _would_ be an array of if it _had_ any elements.

Comment: I guess I would ask you to think about _why_ you believe you need this degree of introspection. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Answer (score 19):

Swift 3: Get an empty array's element type:

```
let cars = [Car]()                    // []
let arrayType = type(of: cars)        // Array<Car>.Type
let carType = arrayType.Element.self  // Car.Type
String(describing: carType)           // "Car"
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work as of Swift 2.0:

```
let nsobjectype = cars.dynamicType.Element()
let newCar = nsobjectype.dynamicType.init()
```

Not sure if it will work in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
let cars = Array<Car>()
let car = cars.dynamicType.Element()
```