# How to find the type of array in swift or objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am facing a issue where I need to find the type of property defined in a class.

For Ex:

```
class Demo {
var employee: [String] = [String]()
var departments: [Int] = [Int]()
}
```

I am able to find that employee or departments is of type Array. However, I am not able to find out which kind of array the variable is. Is it a array of Strings or Numbers?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C arrays are untyped at runtime. So they can't tell you their object type because they don't know it. This doesn't change with lightweight generics; they allow the compiler to perform some checks by declaring intended usage but leave no runtime footprint.

[Get object type from empty Swift Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647858/get-object-type-from-empty-swift-array) tackles the Swift side of things; I couldn't directly speak to that from memory. If it's correct then it looks like it could do with some votes.

Comment: In fact since `NSArray` is allowed to contain objects of different types, they *can't* have a specific type. Even inspecting the array contents would only tell you what it contains *at the moment*, but would be meaningless for typing.

Comment: Yes — even `NSArray<NSString *> *` may contain any object if the user sufficiently requests it; it'll just try to help you to insert only strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can make type checking for objects like

```
for(id object in departments)
{
     if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
     {
          //NSString here
     } 
     else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
     {
          //NSNumber here
     }

}
```

or if you want an object of responding to selector

```
    for(id object in departments)
    {
         if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(methodName:)])
         {
              //object responds to selector here
         }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Meth, Instead of the Class being String and Number it can be anything and I also wanna know that. Either the Class or String informing the same. Lets suppose the property is an array of custom class which is subclass of NSObject

Answer (score 0):

Improving [meth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34881665/4160199) in swift just like objective-c you can check for type of an item in the array

```
for item in library {
    if item is String {
        //Do something with Strings

    } else if item is Int {
        //Do something with Numbers
    }
}
```

You can find all the documentation for swift Type Casting [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).